# How do I get the true type font's height in iOS device?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to get the height of a true-type font.

```
public static Font font = Font.createTrueTypeFont("XXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXX.ttf").derive(36f, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);

int height = font.getHeight()
```

The output value height value is 10 in the simulator but 0 in iOS device(iPhone 7 plus).

Comment: Is the simulator a 7 plus simulator?

Comment: Is it possible the font wasn't created properly? iOS loads the file differently from Android/Simulator when dealing with a ttf file. You need to make sure the file actually loaded. Also the derive version you invoked seems to be incorrect. You're creating a size in pixels with the second argument as weight not unit. You need to use the version that accepts 3 arguments.